# How to move a char in an Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, char

What I am trying to do is to move a character using arrow keys within a 1D or 2D array. I have initialized the array with "a" which means it starts at index #0 but when I swap it doesn't give the intended output instead it gives me something like that:

```
a a a a a a a a a
```

it should be like this

```
                a
```

Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>
#define RIGHT 77
#define LEFT 75
#define UP 72
#define DOWN 80
#define ESC 27



using namespace std;
void gotoxy(int, int);
void swap(char*,char*);

char arr[1024] = { "a"};
char *line_ptr = (char*)arr[0];
char *line_ptr2d =(char*)arr[0];


void main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 1024; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = ' ';
    }

    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int ch;

    do
    {   
        //system("cls");
        int i = 0;
        gotoxy(x, y);
        ch = _getch();

        if (ch == 224)
        {
            ch = _getch();
            switch (ch)
            {
            case LEFT:
                x -= 1;
                line_ptr--;
                swap(&arr[i], &arr[i + 1]);
                //arr[i] = ' ';
                cout << arr[i];
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                x += 1;
                swap(&arr[i], &arr[i + 1]);
                if (arr[i-1] != NULL)
                {
                    arr[i - 1] = ' ';
                }
                cout << arr[i+1];
                break;
            case UP:
                y--;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                y++;
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    } while (1);
} 

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    _COORD pos;
    pos.X = x;
    pos.Y = y;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, pos);
} 

void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your question strictly and then I'll point you to some other issues in your code.

The You **current** problem is that you print incorrectly the data. For example when you "go" right you print the character `'a'` at the *current* position and the you perform your `gotoxy(x,y)`. While you need to put `' '` at you current position and then use `gotoxy(x,y)` with the updated values and put `'a'`.

-

*Some other issues:*

1.

```
char *line_ptr = (char*)arr[0];
char *line_ptr2d =(char*)arr[0];
```

What? Why? Did you mean:

```
char *line_ptr = arr;
char *line_ptr2d = arr;
```

2.

You don't check for being inside your array limits.

3.

You always advance your index `i` no matter if you move left or right. (In such case you should probably use you existing `x` index instead).

4.

```
char arr[1024] = { "a"}; // You probably meant char arr[1024] = {'a'};
```

Answer (score 0):

After swappning two characters in the array, you just display the new one

```
swap(&arr[i], &arr[i + 1]);
cout << arr[i];
```

You also have to write a space over the `i + 1` position to make it go away.